# Microsoft Excel : Display Error if Column A is blank and Column B is not blank

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

User Needs to enter an Excel sheet with 2 Columns A & B.
If B is having a value, then A must not be empty.
If A is empty and B has value, then Excel sheet must throw Error (asking user to enter value in A )or highlight A cell with Color?

How this can be done?

Thanks,
Deepan Mahendran.

Comment: Use data validation custom formula.  Google has many tutorials on how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I tried with if blank formulas, didnt workout as expected.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow @DeepanMahendran. Generally this site is not a "Give me the Code for this" but more of a "Help me find my problem" site. Having said that, and seeing as its your first post, I have provided an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**USING VBA**

Below is a start to what I believe what you want.

What you will need to do is paste this into the Sheet specific Module in your WorkBook VBA project. See image below for more details.

[image]

See script below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim TargetRowColumnAValue As Range
    Dim TargetRowColumnBValue As Range
    Dim CurrentWorkSheet As Worksheet

    Set CurrentWorkSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set TargetRowColumnAValue = CurrentWorkSheet.Cells(Target.Row, "A")
    Set TargetRowColumnBValue = CurrentWorkSheet.Cells(Target.Row, "B")

    If Not TargetRowColumnBValue = Empty Then

        If TargetRowColumnAValue = Empty Then MsgBox "Please ensure that data has been inserted into Column A!"

    End If

    If Not TargetRowColumnAValue = Empty Then

        If TargetRowColumnBValue = Empty Then MsgBox "Please ensure that data has been inserted into Column B!"

    End If

End Sub
```

You can then add or remove any additional formatting to the Cells, etc.

**USING CONDITIONAL FORMATTING**

Using *Conditional Formatting* Select the entire Column B and then in your Home Tab in the Styles section, select *Conditional Formatting* then New Rule then "Use a Formula to determine which cells to format. and then paste the following formula in there `=IF(INDIRECT("RC1",FALSE) <> "", TRUE, FALSE)` you can then select which ever color you like to be fill in the Column B cell. The cell in Column B will then be highlighted for any value in the corresponding Column A cell which is not empty.

Do the same with selecting Column A but using formula `=IF(INDIRECT("RC2",FALSE) <> "", TRUE, FALSE)`.

**NOTE** If for example the Column B cell has any content beside being empty the Column A Cell will be hightlight, this includes a space. You should then use Data Validation with a message referring to the valid values the user may input.

Comment: @DeepanMahendran did it provide you with a solution?

Comment: @Jean-PierreOosthuizen we can keep it simple by using conditional formatting

Comment: @Linga the OP asked for an error message or highlight, how do you activate a message via conditional formatting?

Comment: @Jean-PierreOosthuizen Thanks my friend i have updated it in my answer :)

Comment: @Jean-PierreOosthuizen - It worked ! I just had to remove the second lF Condition.

Comment: @DeepanMahendran if it's the answer you found to be correct then up vote and tick it as correct

Answer (score 0):

Please paste this formula in the **A** column

```css
=IF(B1<>"","?","")
```

And then do conditional formatting in **A** column for which has the value **?** in a colour. Hence **A** column will be highlighted if column **B** has value and **A** is blank.

Or you can keep it simple by doing conditional formatting by using the below formula

```
=AND($B1<>"",$A1="")
```

[image]

Select the **A** column and then go to conventional formatting select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" and enter the above formula and choose the colour to be highlighted then hit ok..

Hope this is what you need..

Comment: Thanks for helping me. But I need to have a value in the Column A, if am using the above formula, I wont be able to enter any value.
For Ex : In Column A, I will always have only 2 values. "1" or "2".

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional formatting. Make a new rule, and insert this formula and choose the color you want to be highlighted. Enter this formula and choose the range you need formatted. In this case I did `A1:A100`

```
=IF($A1<>"","",INDIRECT("RC[1]",0))
```

[image]

Comment: @Linga, I am not sure I follow? It does what the OP asks or did I miss something?

Comment: @Dave column A should be highlighted if  column B is not empty and A is empty if im not wrong your formula is not doing it

Comment: @Linga, you are right, I miss read the question. I thought it was if Column B was empty. I will update my answer.